# Probability puzzler involving roots of unity

Tags: probability, contest-math

**Problem:** Let $v$ and $w$ be roots of $z^{1997} = 1$ chosen at random (uniformly and independently). What is the probability that $|v + w| \ge \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 3}$?

This problem comes from the 1997 AIME.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain the problem they see with this question?

Comment: The purpose of this site is to help people, both the askers and future readers. It's not meant to be a contest.

Comment: you are welcome to post whatever you like, and if people think it doesn't belong they will downvote and perhaps close it.  You asked why you're getting downvotes, and I explained it to you; I"m not trying to get into an argument.

Comment: @vadim123 Ok, point taken. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @vadim123: Whenever one asks a question, there is, [on the same page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), the option to post an answer simultaneously.  Asking questions to which one already knows the answer is *expressly* permitted.

Comment: To be fair, the question was much more distasteful in its original form.

Comment: @MJD, I didn't downvote, I was explaining why others might.  The original post was stated as a contest.  Several clarifying comments have since been deleted.

Comment: @vadim123 To be honest, I probably would have downvoted such a question myself. It was a bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of symmetry, we can take $v=1$.  Then we let $w=\exp(i \theta)$  We have $$|v+w|=|1+\exp(i \theta)|=|1+\cos \theta + i \sin \theta|=\sqrt{(1+\cos \theta)^2+\sin^2 \theta}=\sqrt {2+2\cos \theta}$$  So we need $\cos \theta \gt \frac {\sqrt 3}2$ or $-\frac \pi 6\lt \theta \lt \frac \pi 6$  This gives $166$ choices for $w$ on each side of $1$, plus $1$ itself, for a chance of $\frac{333}{1997}$